# Не подключается удаленно к базе данных MySQL Python

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, база-данных, phpmyadmin, ssh

Подключаюсь к серверу при помощи ssh, но к базе данных, лежащей на этом сервере, подключиться не могу. **Все данные ввожу правильно. Проверил, SQL-сервер работает на 3306 порту**. Указываю его, но все равно не помогает. База данных лежит на phpMyAdmin. *В чем моя ошибка?*

**Выдает такую ошибку все время:**

```
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([WinError **10061]...)
```

**Код**

```
import paramiko
import pymysql
host = "x.x.x.x"
port = 22
username ="cv86943"
password = "xxxxxx"

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(host,port,username,password)

print("1") #1 writes, so the connection to the hosting is successful
conn = pymysql.connect(host = "localhost",user = "cv86943_letter", password = "12345678", db = "cv86943_letter")

print("2") #But 2 does not write anymore
ssh.close()
```

UPD: Прочитал про особой SSL-туннель, не стоит ли через него попробовать подключиться?

Comment: Вы уж определитесь, через что вы подключаетесь. Если через ssh-туннель, то нужно его подключить. Если без ssh-туннеля, то `host = "localhost"` конечно же не будет работать

Comment: А какой хост в таком случае нужен?

Comment: Или мой подход в корне неверен?

Comment: Тот, который принимает принимает соединения к базе на порту 3306, то есть скорее всего IP-адрес сервера

Comment: Юхууу! Подключил, просто указав ip адрес сервера, спасибо вам большое)